# Parsing out underscore in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that Im pulling data from a form when I do var_dump($_POST) I get

```
array(2) { ["objectName"]=> string(7) "TestOBJ" ["Object_Class"]=> string(12) "Object Class" }
```

thats fine except I want the "Object_Class" to be "Object Class" Because Im trying to match it with another string with the same value but wont match because of the underscore. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace('_', ' ', $variable);
```

**EDIT:** It would be overkill if this is the only key he needed to modify, but I was suggesting a more general solution.

```
$newPOST = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $newPOST[str_replace('_',' ', $key)] = $val;
}

$_POST = $newPOST;
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Absolutely not. He wants to edit the array index, and you can't do it this way.

Comment: Yea with that my var_dump is: array(1) { [""]=> string(12) "Object Class" }

Comment: sorry there was a type in the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['Object Class'] = $_POST['Object_Class'];
unset( $_POST['Object_Class']);
```

Comment: Erhm let me be a little more specific. I have a list of values that are randomly generated no $_Post value are the same, but any value with a space between them gets an underscore put where the post variable name is. I think this is the right idea but not sure

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = $_POST;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
{
    if(strpos($key, '_') !== false)
    {
        unset ($arr[$key]);    
        $new_key = str_replace('_', ' ', $key);    
        $arr[$new_key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you only want to change 'index values'

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?